# Unable to save the full input stream received from Bluetooth to a byte array

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android Bluetooth image transfer app in which I am sending bytes to another device the device is receiving the input stream but I want to store the whole input stream in a byte array and then store the image in the phone memory.

But every time I am successfully able to store a blank image. I am unable to store the full image into byte array while receiving the input stream.

Comment: What kind of response you are awaiting for?

Comment: `the device is receiving the input stream`. Is that an Android device?

Comment: yes it is, i have figured out how to add the buffers to a byte array and the image is succesfully tranfered. But now my problem is , " I am not able to understand when the data is fully transferred ". Is there any method to check whether the device has fully received the buffers or not? @greenapps Unless i check my phone whether a proper image exists or not :p

Comment: shall i share a part of the code? @greenapps

Comment: byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];bytes =mmInStream.read(buffer);
  output.write(buffer,0,bytes);
 byte file[] = output.toByteArray();
onPictureTaken(file);

Comment: Before you send the image send a number indicating the amount of bytes that you will send. So send file size. Then you know how much you have to read. Please dont post code in comments. Put it in your post!

Comment: I am trying to do so, but is there no other way to check?

Comment: What do you have in mind?